# Проблема с записью строки в фаил

Tags: shell, perl, sha256

Нужна помощь, хешируя строку через perl, мне нужно что бы хешированная строка записывалась в файл следующей строкой. Например, есть выходной файл result.txt, в нем первые строки уже заняты, мне нужно что бы результат записывался следующей свободной строкой.
Использую

```
perl -M'Digest::SHA qw(sha256_hex)' -ne 'chomp; print sha256_hex($_), "\n"' test.txt > result.txt
```

то есть сейчас при выполнении команды создается постоянно новый файл result с результатом хеширования в первой строке.

Comment: А вы печатайте сначала исходную строку, потом хеш

Comment: Этот вопрос не имеет отношения к собственно Perl. Ответы в вопросе [How do I append text to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17701989/1186729)

Answer (score 1):

Следует использовать [оператор `>>`](https://itisgood.ru/2019/08/14/kak-dobavit-tekst-v-konec-fajla-v-linux/) вместо `>` при перенаправлении в поток вывода:

```bash
perl -M'Digest::SHA qw(sha256_hex)' -ne 'chomp; print sha256_hex($_), "\n"' test.txt >> result.txt
```